# Installing Android market applications via USB

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to install an application from the Android market to the phone via USB? The problem is that I don't have access to internet on my phone, so I need to know an alternative method of installing Android applications to it. 
Getjar and some other websites offer apk files, but they are not market applications.

Comment: Probably belongs on Android Enthusiasts, but it's not an option for migration. Think a mod has to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `adb install file.apk`. For more info about adb take a look at the [Android developer documentation for adb](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can only use "adb install file.apk" if you have the apk file on your computer. I think you don't have mode to install apk from the market directly :(

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested but we can give it a try.

1. Make an AVD and do some settings to make it look real like adding IMEI etc and login with your g-mail account.
2. Now, it has network access from you PC through tunneling. Your AVD
   will be having full access to market and you can install any app
   directly.
3. Install any app-backup application and backup all the apps you want to install to your phone.
4. You can easily open or mount the SD-Card memory of your AVD, [just google it].
5. Browse your apps and copy to your Phone through USB.
6. Now browse in your phone and install the app you wish.
   [Minor details are skipped like you need to enable "Unknown Source" etc.]

If somebody test it then please share the result as now a days I am little busy for extra-curriculum. ;-)

Happy Coding.